# How to neglect emojis when posting messages to slack using slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack POST api call which I am doing from my application:-

```
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=response, as_user=False, username="Slack bot")
```

The issue which I am encountering is that the response may contain error logs and can have text like

> Error in /:hive:/SomeError....

When this gets posted to slack, it thinks of :hive: as an emoji and prints emoji of hive instead of :hive:, which I don't want.

How to do this? I have tried putting mrkdwn as false, but it didn't help. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options:

- You can directly format your string as code. Then Slack will not parse for emojis.
- You can send your message in a block, which gives you the option to explicitly turn off emojis.

Example

```py
import slack
import os
import json

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

client.chat_postMessage(        
    channel='general',
    text='`Error in /:hive:/SomeError....`'
)

client.chat_postMessage(        
    channel='general',    
    blocks=json.loads("""
        [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Error in /:hive:/SomeError....",
                    "emoji": false
                }
            }
        ]
    """)
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I wasn't getting a chance of testing this. This worked! Thanks